# Backend receiving wrong data for post method using URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: ios, node.js, swift

I am using `URLSession.shared.dataTask` to post image data in base64 formate but at backend I am receiving wrong data ("+" replaced with " "). Post data contain different parameters with image data in base64 but in `req.body` I found that in body all occurrence of "+" replaced with " ". In postman and Android it works and stores image.

```
func postDataToServer ( method : String, api_for : String, postData : String, completion: @escaping (_ reponse : [String:AnyObject]?, _ success : Int, _ message : String) -> Void) {

    let getUrl = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/timeSheet/saveImage"

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: getUrl)! as URL,
                                      cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 60.0)
    request.httpMethod = method
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers


    if method == "POST" {
        var post = postData
        post.append("&devicename=\(UIDevice.current.modelName) \(UIDevice.current.systemVersion)")
        let postData = NSMutableData(data: "\(post)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        request.httpBody = postData as Data
        let datastring = NSString(data: postData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    }
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            completion (nil, 1, (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        do {
            let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            let response = self.responseData(data: responseObject)
            completion (response.reponse, response.statuscode, response.message)

        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
            completion (nil, 1,"Data Formate Error")
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Backend code node.js:

```
  router.post('/saveImage', async (req, res) =>{
    var response = {
      "statuscode" : 0,
      "statusmessage" : "Failed", 
      "result" : [],
    }
    var rawBody = String(req.body.photo)
    const base64Data = rawBody.replace(/^data:([A-Za-z-+/]+);base64,/, '');
    console.log(req.body.base64Data)

  require("fs").writeFile("/Users/sid/Desktop/FreeLance/WPD/out.jpeg", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send( JSON.stringify( response ));
  });
  })
```

Is anything wrong in code ?
**Should I use Alamofire ?**

Comment: Kinda hard to tell without example data. My guess is that the regex on the server side (`const base64Data = rawBody.replace(/^data:([A-Za-z-+/]+);base64,/, '');`) is wrong.

Comment: regex used only to remove "data:image/jpeg;base64," string from image data base64 but its work with postman call and android device.

Comment: @sid-mhatre : You are making a multipart request and not the plain post request, I don't see the content type set or formatting data to suite the needs of multipart request

Comment: I am not making multipart request  ` let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ]`.